# Visual Studio 2010 - Interop.ActiveDs.dll not getting copied to IIS Publish bin folder

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, publishing

I created a VS2010 WCF service project.

I added a reference to Interop.ActiveDs.dll to the service project.  As a side note, Stdole.dll is in the GAC on my machine.

When I build the service project, Interop.ActiveDs.dll is copied to the bin directory under the project folder, but when I publish the project using File System publish, Interop.ActiveDs.dll is not copied to the bin directory in the publish folder.

What would cause the publish action to NOT copy the assembly to the bin directory? What can I do to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: When you select the reference for this dll in you project what is the setting for "Copy Local"?

Comment: @KevinJunghans: In my project it is False, and grayed out so I can't change it.